# Checking if a PDF file is password-protected

Tags: pdf

I know of several tools/libraries that can do this but I want to know if this is possible with just opening up the file as a text file and looking for a keyword.

Comment: You should follow the PDF spec. And this best done using well-built libraries. It's just not that easy to search for a keyword. It may work today but not tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in about 4 lines of Python with the [`slate`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate) package:

```
>>> import slate
>>> with open('file.pdf, 'rb') as f:
...     doc = slate.PDF(f, 'password')
>>> 'keyword' in doc.text()
True
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I develop `slate`, feel free to take a look at other tools too.

Comment: Hm. I would expect `doc.text()` to return the text of the document as a string. Then `'keyword' in doc.text()` would just check if the string `'keyword'` is a substring of the document.